# How to check if a specific value in Kendo UI Multiselect was picked?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

Html:

```
<select id="days" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select days...">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>          
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>          
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>          
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>          
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#days").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoClose: false
});

var days = $("#days").data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

How do I find out if a specific item was selected?  For instance, how do I know if user selected Friday?

Note that I can select multiple items here.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/multiselect#methods-value ?

Comment: @LarsHöppner value method only sets the multiselect with specific items.  It returns everything that's selected - you can't query a specific item.

Comment: well..iterate over all selected values and check whether the one you're looking for is in there?

Comment: @LarsHöppner Yeah, that's what I'll do, but I was hoping for a method.  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API method to check whether a specific item is selected, but you can easily create one, e.g. like this:

```
kendo.ui.MultiSelect.fn.isSelected = function (key) {
    var selectedItems = this.value();
    return selectedItems.indexOf(key) > -1;
};
```

which you can then use like this:

```
$("#days").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoClose: false
});

var days = $("#days").data("kendoMultiSelect");

$("#button").click(function() {
    console.log("is it friday?", days.isSelected("Friday"));
});
```

Comment: Works great.  I simplified the code a bit to remove looping.

Comment: in that case the ternary operator is also unnecessary; also: note that when you initialize the widget with a Kendo DataSource, you'd have to check whether the item is an object and compare to `selectedItems[i][this.options.dataValueField]` instead

Comment: Even better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the dataItems() function:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/multiselect#methods-dataItems

And then you can iterate the selected items like this:

```
days.dataItems().forEach(function(element, index, array) {    
    //dataItems() returns the selected items
    // Work on each element, element.value
  });
```

Here is a jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/vijiq/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `switch` a try.

```
var day = document.getElementById("days").value;
switch(day) {
    case "Monday":
        yourFunction();
        break;
    case "Tuesday":
        anotherFunction();
        break;

    ... etc.
}
```

Alright, Try something like this instead? Untested, mind you.

```
var days = [];
var options = document.querySelectorAll("#days option");
var i = 0, length = options.length;
for (i; i < length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
        days.push(options[i].value);
    }
}
alert(days);
```

Comment: I can select multiple items in this dropdown.  This code won't work.